# getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); Object cannot be converted to Lekarz- Gui FX

Tags: java, javafx

I have problem with getSelectionModel()
I want that, when I clink on listview, aplication download id_lekarza to id.
Lekarz is object, it has id_lekarza, name, surname, id.
Class Lekarz

```
public Lekarz(String imie, String nazwisko, String pesel) {
    this.id_lekarza=id_lekarza;
    this.imie = imie;
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    this.pesel = pesel;

}

public Lekarz(){};
```

My Controller

```
dellekarz.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->{                                
                 if(viewlekarz.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null){

Lekarz lekarz= new Lekarz(); 
            lekarz = viewlekarz.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            int id = lekarz.getId_lekarza();
```

It is part of code, because i have also hibernat

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: What do you expect to be happening and what is actually happening? Are you getting any errors? If so, include those errors in your question.

Comment: can you please elaborate more, on where the problem is ?

Comment: Why create a new `Lekarz` object, if you drop the object without using it anyway? (You overwrite the variable value with the value from the selection model.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found problem.
I did @FXML, private ListView viewlekarz, it was bad. I fix this problem, i change @FXML ListView viewlekarz